# For all sets A, B, and C, if A ⊆ B, then A∩C ⊆ B∩C

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove each of these statements. Use equation editor for mathematical symbols, formulas,
predicates, equations, and so forth. You may use all the proof techniques we've used so far:
direct proof, existential instantiation, generalizing from generic particular, counterexamples,
contradiction, contraposition, etc., as well as basic algebra.

For all sets A, B, and C, if A ⊆ B, then A∩C ⊆ B∩C

I'm having trouble with this one. Can someone help?

Comment: What *exactly* does $A \subseteq B$ mean?

Comment: A is a subset of B.

Comment: What *exactly* does "A is a subset of B" mean?

Comment: If you don't understand that, you're not gonna get the problem dude.

Comment: I think he gets the problem. I think @UmbertoP. is trying to get you to think about the problem some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about this in terms of elements. If $x \in A$, then we have immediately that $x \in B$, correct? What about the converse? Does that hold? Of course not. If an element is in the superset ($B$), we know nothing about whether it is contained in $A$.

Now look at intersection. What can we say if $x \in (A \cap C)$? We say that $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. Now apply the logic for a subset relation that I outlined above. That's your proof.

Comment: But how do we prove that x∈(A∩C)?  I understand everything you are saying and how we prove it.  But how do we know  x∈(A∩C)?

Comment: We aren't proving that $x \in (A \cap C)$. We are supposing that $x \in (A \cap C)$. We want to conclude that if $A \subseteq B$ and $x \in (A \cap C)$, then $x \in (B \cap C)$.